# How do you get the name of a google account in Python using their email?

Tags: python, gmail

In Gmail it allows you to see who you are sending it to because it correlates email address and name. I have been doing research and haven't found any methods of just getting the first and last name of the account as the Gmail client does using the email address. Does anyone know a way? It must work on Python 3.10

Comment: check the people api it will return profile information

Comment: It is unsupported of Python 3.10

Comment: Um No.  the Google People api is a rest api and supported by any language that can run a HTTP Get or HTTP post calls.    [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) supports python 3.7 and newer.   No idea where you are getting your information from   They even have a [QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python)

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client

Comment: It says its unsupported in 3.10

Comment: I have know idea where you are reading that it says on the page you linked:  **Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 are fully supported and tested.**   May I suggest you try.

Comment: OMG I'm just illiterate I'm sorry

Comment: First time I have read that LOL